# Animating multiple objects together

Tags: animation

I'm trying to animate multiple objects together in one animation, but can't seem to do that.

I have 5 cubes. I created 4 animations, but Blender automatically created another 4 animations for 4 cubes, called `Cube001.Action`, `Cube002.Action`, and so on.

Basically, when I move one cube, it modifies its position in another animation rather than the one I want, and disappears from the animation I need.

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 1):

Turn the action editor window into "dopesheet" and you will see all your animations.
Every object has his own action, 5 objects animation will consist of 5 actions, editable together through the dopesheet.

Comment: Here is the problem. Each object is changing in a different animation. How to make them all change in the same ?  Picture : http://i.imgur.com/VEEBNCC.png

Comment: I want them all to be part of "MoveRight"

Comment: I somehow managed to do it with a different animation but I am not sure how. Picture : http://i.imgur.com/RKWHDP9.png

Comment: Ok, found out how I did it. If I touch an object, it says it's in "Move Right" in the Dope Sheet, but it then moves to the center where the first cube is, so you can't see it. Picture : http://i.imgur.com/kmt9yft.png

Comment: “MoveRight” is the name of an action datablock which – in your first image – is assigned to the object named “cube”; “cube.001” has “Cube.001Action”, etc....
Theese datablocks contain only informations about location, rotation, scale (which change every keyframe of the action).
You can assign this datablock to many objects (as you did in the 4th image) and you'll obtain that every object will move exactly in the same way (and if the objects are equal, they'll perfectly overlap each other).

Comment: This is the way Blender is structured: you can't address part of an action to an object and another part to another object: you have to use 2 different actions.
Why do you want to have everything in one action (which, as I said, is impossible)? If you export a multiple actions  animation every exporter will address the right data to the right object (tihs is the normal, common way to work with Blender).

Answer (score 0):

Use an armature that has a bone centered at each cube, with each cube parented to bone without deformation. The armature will then be animated in pose mode, and each movement will be contained in one single action instead of five separate animations across five objects.

Answer (score 0):

Found an easy way to do it, just rename all the NLA tracks using exactly the same name, export it and there's should be a single animation